# mysql-connector-c++ 8.0 connection refused

Tags: c++, mysql, oracle, mysql-connector-c

I'm using the mysql-connector-c++ 8.0 after getting it working with great difficulty and now the uri I've entered is as their mentioning in the docs but the connection is refused.

What the doc says:

```
Client cli("user:password@host_name/db_name", ClientOption::POOL_MAX_SIZE, 7);
```

My Code:

```
_mysql_client = std::make_unique<mysqlx::Client>("mysqlx://root:asdasd@localhost/asdasd");

    try {
        mysqlx::Session s = _mysql_client->getSession();
        CoreLog->info("Successfully connected to mysql server on {}.", conn_uri);
    } catch (const mysqlx::Error &err) {
        CoreLog->info("Could not connect to mysql server on {} due to {}.", conn_uri, err.what());
    }
```

and i get this error

```
[20:34:36.993] Core: Could not connect to mysql server on root:asdasd@localhost/asdasd due to CDK Error: Connection refused (generic:61).
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: Do you have a mysql server running on localhost on the default mysql port?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, i can connect to it via command line using the same user / pass

Comment: But can you connect over tcp? Mysql might be listening over a unix socket.

Comment: @AlanBirtles it listens on tcp by default. I haven't changed that and just switched from connector version 1.1 to 8.0. It was working fine on the former.

Comment: You could try explicitly setting the port? `"mysqlx://root:asdasd@localhost:3306/asdasd"`

Comment: Tried that and now it gives `CDK Error: unexpected message.`

Comment: Looks like mysqlx listens on port 33060 by default: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-port-reference/en/mysql-ports-reference-tables.html. Are you sure you want to use mysqlx? Presumably `"mysql://root:asdasd@localhost/asdasd"` uses the standard mysql protocol on port 3306

Comment: Actually looks like this api only supports mysql x, I guess you need to enable that on your server

Comment: @AlanBirtles I spend the whole day rewriting my code to suit mysqlx 8.0 and now I realise its a document store. I thought they called 1.1.11 "legacy code" because it was an upgrade or something. Thanks though.

Comment: From what I'm reading it was developed to enable the document store but also allows access to standard sql databases https://insidemysql.com/tag/x-devapi/

Comment: @AlanBirtles that is true, I managed to connect by installing mysqlsh and enabling the X plugin.

Comment: @AlanBirtles maybe you could help me with this issue as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54203780/closed-cursor-error-mysql-connector-c-8-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqlx::Client` is for connection to the new Mysql X protocol. This listens on a different port (33060 by default instead of 3306) which is the cause of the "connection refused" message.

You need to install and enable the Mysql protocol X plugin. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install.html for instructions.