# Closed cursor error mysql connector c++ 8.0

Tags: c++, mysql, c, mysql-connector

I'm using mysql connector 8.0 and the below code throws a Closed cursor error when trying to fetch the row.

```
        std::string query = "SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `gender`, `email`, `group_id`, `state`, `unban_time`, `expiration_time`, `last_login`, `last_ip`, `birth_date`, `character_slots`, `pincode`, `pincode_expiry` FROM `game_account` WHERE username = ?;";

        mysqlx::RowResult res = server->get_mysql_session().sql(query).bind(username).execute();

        try {
            mysqlx::Row record = res.fetchOne();
```

Error:

```
CDK Error: get_rows: Closed cursor
```

Comment: We need a [mcve] but at a guess your `get_mysql_session()` method is returning a temproary session object which is destroyed at the end of the line which then makes the result object invalid.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I think you're right, thanks.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't understand how that works though, could you please elaborate? I've added in the code I changed which made it work. How is it so shortlived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`server->get_mysql_session()` returns a temporary `Session` object. All temporaries are destroyed at the end of the statement in which they were created.

As the session is destroyed before you call `fetchOne` it fails.

For example this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A()\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()\n"; }
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const A& a) { os << "\nA<<"; return os; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << "line1\n";
    std::cout << "line2" << A() << "\n";
    std::cout << "line3\n";
}
```

produces the following output:

```
line1
A()
line2
A<<
~A()
line3
```